# Does Rare Replay include the N64 originals, or the 360 remakes?

Tags: rare-replay

I'm considering buying Rare Replay, but I'm wondering about a couple of the games included inside. Specifically, Banjo-Kazooie and Banjo-Tooie.

Are they the N64 originals, or the XBLA remakes with fully implemented Stop'n'Swop?

Depending on the answer, I might just wait for the upcoming backward-compatibility feature and buy the XBLA versions, although Rare Replay *does* seem very appealing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a review of the Rare Replay that explains that there are a mix of the XBox 360 and Nintendo 64 games thrown in together. Banjo Kazooie, Banjo-Tooie, and Perfect Dark are all in their XBox 360 form according to the article. Read the quote below. (Source follows, beware of adult language within in the full article).

> Making the software bundle even stranger, three of the N64-era games—Banjo-Kazooie, Banjo-Tooie, and Perfect Dark—are offered in the form of their Xbox 360 up-rezzed ports, subject to all that I just wrote about how 360 games work with the collection. Four others—Killer Instinct Gold, Blast Corps, Jet Force Gemini and Conker’s Bad Fur Day—are running on a Nintendo 64 emulator. Yes, the Xbox One is running an N64 emulator. Presumably Nintendo has been informed. Strangely, Rare Replay is not using the Xbox remake of Conker. The N64 version is still technically impressive with good graphics and a lot of funny voice-acting, so it’s not a big deal and probably for the best.

[Article Source](http://kotaku.com/rare-replay-the-kotaku-review-1721781195)